# how do i set the background color of my form to what the user picks from colordialog?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

how do i set the background color of my form to what the user picks from colordialog?

Comment: **Duplicate** of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214329/allowing-user-to-choose-their-own-color-for-form-background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply assign the [`BackColor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ktb99cf2.aspx) property of the form with the value of the [`Color`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.colordialog.color.aspx) property of the `ColorDialog`:

```
Dim cd As New ColorDialog()
If cd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
    Me.BackColor = cd.Color
End If
```

Comment: Only if you want the color dialog to show each time the form is displayed (which I doubt). Put a button or a menu item on the form instead, and put it in the click event of that control.